# Discord.js detect when user is typing

Tags: events, discord.js, bots, typing

is there a possibility I can detect If a user starts/stops typing?
I use the Discord.js Webpack Version 12 and I can't seem to find any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`typingStart()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=e-typingStart) event, which will trigger when a user starts typing.

```js
client.on('typingStart', (channel, user) => {
  console.log(`${user.username} is typing in ${channel.name}`)
};
```

---

There is also the [`User.typingIn()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/User?scrollTo=typingIn) method, which will check if a user is typing in a specified channel, and return a `boolean`.

```js
if (<user>.typingIn(<channel>)) 
  console.log(`${<user>.username} in typing in ${<channel>.name}`);
```

(You can also use the [`typingDurationIn()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/User?scrollTo=typingDurationIn) and [`typingSinceIn()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/User?scrollTo=typingSinceIn) methods)

---

Lastly, you can look at the [`TextChannel.typing`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=typing) property of a `TextChannel` to detect if *anyone* is typing in that channel.

```js
if (<channel>.typing)
  console.log(`Somebody is typing in ${channel.name}`);
```

(You can also use the [`typingCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=typingCount) property to see how *many* people are typing in the given channel)

Comment: wow, it worked thank you, but is there also an event that gets called when a user stops typing?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You can visit [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client) docs page to view every `discord.js` event if you're curious.

Comment: set a timeout that always gets recreated to the onChange of the input field and that triggers your "stop typing". That's how we solved the stop-typing problem

Comment: oh ok, I just used an onmessage event as a "stopTyping event". It may not be always correct but its okay